# Am I using static correctly?

Tags: java, static

Lately I've been reading lots of posts about using `static`. I read a lot about `static` being abused. I want to be sure I am using it correctly in this Manager class:

```
public class SignManager
{
    private static HashMap<String, List<GameSign>> signsBySection   = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, List<GameServer>> serversBySection = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<String, GameServer>serverNames = new HashMap<>();
    private static HashMap<Sign, GameSign> gameSignBySign = new HashMap<>();
    private static List<GameServer> availableServers = new ArrayList<>();
    private static List<GameServer> displayedServers = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addSign(String section, Sign sign)
    {
        List<GameSign> signs = signsBySection.get(section);

        if(signs == null)
            signsBySection.put(section, signs = new ArrayList<>());

        GameSign gameSign = new GameSign(section, sign.getLocation());

        signs.add(gameSign);
        gameSignBySign.put(sign, gameSign);
    }

    public static void addServers(String section, List<String> range)
    {
        List<GameServer> servers = SignManager.serversBySection.get(section);

        if(servers == null)
            SignManager.serversBySection.put(section, servers = new ArrayList<>());

        for(String s : range)
        {
            GameServer server = new GameServer(s);

            servers.add(server);
            serverNames.put(s, server);
        }
    }

    public static void setAvailable(GameServer server)
    {
        availableServers.add(server);
    }

    public static void replaceDisplayed(GameServer old, GameServer newServer)
    {
        removeDisplayed(old);
        displayedServers.add(newServer);
    }

    public static void removeDisplayed(GameServer server)
    {
        displayedServers.remove(server);

        if(server != null)
            server.setSign(null);
    }

    public static boolean isDisplayed(GameServer server)
    {
        return displayedServers.contains(server);
    }

    public static boolean isAvailable(GameServer server)
    {
        return availableServers.contains(server);
    }

    public static void tick()
    {
        for(GameSign sign : getAllGameSigns())
            sign.tick();

        GameSign.addDot();
    }

    public static GameServer getGameServer(String name)
    {
        return serverNames.get(name);
    }

    public static GameServer getNextAvailableServer()
    {
        if(availableServers.size() == 0)
            return null;

        GameServer server = availableServers.get(0);
        availableServers.remove(0);
        return server;
    }

    public static GameSign getGameSign(Sign sign)
    {
        return gameSignBySign.get(sign);
    }

    public static Set<Map.Entry<String, List<GameSign>>> getSignsBySection()
    {
        return signsBySection.entrySet();
    }

    public static Collection<GameServer> getAllServers()
    {
        return serverNames.values();
    }

    public static Collection<GameSign> getAllGameSigns()
    {
        return gameSignBySign.values();
    }
}
```

I also read that if the class has a state, it shouldn't be `static`. So does using `static` Maps mean that the class has a state and am I using `static` correctly here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is all of this static at all? Why not just make them all *instance* variables and *instance* methods, and make sure that where you need a `SignManager`, you've got an appropriate instance? Is it unthinkable that there would be two different `SignManager` instances with different servers etc? (In particular, it makes it a lot easier to test that way...)

Comment: There is only one SignManager needed because all GameSigns are saved together.

Comment: But why not just create one *instance* of `SignManager` which you make available to everything that needs it? Again, that will make testing easier - as well as future expansion to a later system where they're *not* all saved together...

Comment: I agree with Jon.  You should look into using the Singleton pattern with your SignManager class. See here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/singleton_pattern.htm

Comment: Could you explain why static is bad for testing? Also, I am sure that there won't be any future expansions on this class.

Comment: a) you need to do more work to clear down the global state at the start or end of each test; simply constructing a new object is much cleaner. b) your tests can't be run in parallel within the same classloader. Basically it's global state, which is harder to reason about and work with. As for being sure of the future - my experience is that that's rarely a good idea.

Comment: As for performance, does it make any difference?

Comment: One reason static is bad for testing because if you have separate test cases then the ordering of your test cases will mater (since the static values will live across multiple test cases).  So you either have to reset all static values between each test or enforce a test case ordering, neither of which are "good practice".

Comment: *"As for performance, does it make any difference?"* Static methods avoid virtual calls, which is a very small cost. Much smaller than what you are doing inside the methods. So not really.

Comment: What about Utility classes which have a Random.java variable? Since Random has a state. Should I use Singleton for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the face of it, I would say that you are *not* using static correctly. The class maintains state which is affected by the addServers and addSign methods. The state is maintained statically which means that if you had two distinct instance of the SignManager object, both would share the same state. This may be what you want - it may not.

If it *is* what you want, then using the Singleton pattern provides a more usual way of achieving this. If it is not what you want, then you should consider changing the static variable to instance variables ( and making the corresponding changes to the method signatures )

Answer (score 1):

If you make everything `static` as you have above, it will make you code more tightly coupled. You could remove all of the `static` keywords from this class and use instances of it in other components and your code will still be correct.

Now if you wanted to make a different implementation of your class (or have more than one instance of it for some reason), you don't have to change that much, just inject the new implementation of the class into the components that use it.

It is also easier to write unit tests for classes that do not use `static` calls.

This article might help shed more light on why it's best to avoid them... http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/how-not-to-do-dependency-injection-the-static-or-singleton-container